# Core data - Data fetching

Tags: ios, core-data, storyboard, xcode6

I am using storyboard and and coredata in my app. In the home screen i want to list all my audio file details and in a button click i want to navigate to another screen and record a new file and save that file in database. When pressing back button i reached to home screen and i want to display the saved audio files in a tableview. Table row count is showing correctly. But the audio details are not correct.  But when i stop and rebuild the app it is showing correctly. I wrote the code for reloading the tableview in viewWillApper.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [tableview reloadData];
    [self loadFiles];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AudioDetails" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

    [request setIncludesSubentities:NO];     NSError *err;
    NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&err];
    return count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AudioCell";
    AudioCell *cell = (AudioCell *)[tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (AudioCell *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell configurePlayerButton];
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"AudioDetails" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
        if(audionames == nil)
            audionames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [audionames addObject:[info valueForKey:@"audioName"]];


        //NSManagedObject *details = [info valueForKey:@"details"];
        //NSLog(@"Zip: %@", [details valueForKey:@"zip"]);
    }
     cell.titleLabel.text = [audionames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
- (IBAction)SaveRecordingBtnClicked:(id)sender {

       NSString *soundFilePath = [[self getDocumentDirectoryPath]
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:OrginalAudioFileName];
    NSURL *path=[NSURL URLWithString:soundFilePath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAudioPlayer* avAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:path error:&error];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    AudioDetails *audioDetails = [NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AudioDetails"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:soundFilePath error:&error];
    NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];


    NSDate *fileCreationDate = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];
    int duration = avAudioPlayer.duration;

    [audioDetails setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",OrginalAudioFileName] forKey:@"audioName"];

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you are not using NSFetchResultController. This will make your life much easier

Comment: You're doing fetch requests in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? */me has heart attack, dies*

Comment: OK that wasn't helpful. Could you describe how, precisely, the details are "not correct"? What do you expect to see, and what do you see instead of that?

Comment: suppose there are 2 audio files in database currently. I recorded a new audio file and then press back button. It displays 3 audio file in tableview. But the details of newly recorded one (like audio name , file size , duration etc) are not correct. It is showing the same as that of audio file saved previously.

Comment: Thanks all. Now it is working . I used NSFetchResultController. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you  Adeel Ur Rehman for remembering me about NSFetchResultController